# Gazebo recording stream from camera

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm simulating a quadrotor with Gazebo and I'd like to know if there's a way to save the image stream acquired from the camera mounted on the vehicle into an .avi file, in other words I'd like to take a video of what the camera sees, is it possible?

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67560/gazebo-recording-stream-from-camera/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2013-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can record images using `rosbag record` and then combine them into a video:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2013-07-18**:
exactly what i was looking for, thanks!